# Algorithm to compute fastest method of collecting $k$ re-spawning items which spawn at $n$ specified points

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

Let $V = v_1, \dots, v_n$ be the locations the items can spawn at, and let $U = u_1, \dots, u_k$ be the current positions of the items. We will assume a new items spawns instantly every time we collect an item, so there are always $k$ items (Assume uniform distribution for spawn location). Let $w$ be the current position of the character. Then $S = (V, U, w)$ is the state of the game.

Assume the character can move at a constant speed, so the time metric we care about is proportional to the distance between two points.

Essentially I want a function $\text{bestItem}(S)$ that tells me which item in $U$ to go to first to maximize the number of items I collect per hour.

This seems similar to shortest path on a clique with weighted edges, but it doesn't stop after one step. Or a traveling salesman problem where the traveling salesman doesn't know all the locations he needs to visit from the start.

Is there a name for this problem? I am curious if it is already solved, and how good the greedy method of just always taking the nearest item is compared to the optimal method. Or the method of computing the shortest path through the points of $U$, and updating it after some number of spawns.

Has anyone worked with this type of problem and point me at some reading material? My interest is inspired by video games which have mechanics like this.

Thanks.

Comment: The greedy method is infinitely bad in the worst case: consider two items $a$ and $b$ at distance $R$, and two other items $c$ and $d$ at distance $1$ such that the distance between $a$ or $b$ to $c$ or $d$ is greater than $R$. Suppose the character starts on top of item $a$, and let $k=3$. Then, the hero will go back and forth between items $a$ and $b$, but here the optimal case would be to go to $c$ or $d$ first and then back and forth between $c$ and $d$. Since $R$ can be arbitrary, the error can be made arbitrary.

Comment: Also, are you planning to compute it? I mean, you can probably let the position of the character and the positions of all objects $n \binom nk$ as a state and model it as a markov decision process with infinite horizon.

Comment: If your horizon is finite (the game ends at a known finite time $T$) then this problem is hard by a reduction from TSP. Are you looking at infinite horizon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially the disk scheduling problem in a general metric space. You can read about it in the paper [Reordering Buffers
for General Metric Spaces](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~englert/publications/buffer_toc10.pdf) for example:

> **Abstract**: In the reordering buffer problem, we are given an input
>   sequence of requests for service each of which corresponds to a point
>   in a metric space. The cost of serving the requests heavily depends on
>   the processing order. When serving a request the cost is equal to the
>   distance, in the metric space, between this request and the previously
>   served request. A reordering buffer with storage capacity k can be
>   used to reorder the input sequence in a restricted fashion so as to
>   construct an output sequence with lower service cost. This simple and
>   universal framework is useful for many applications in computer
>   science and economics, e. g., disk scheduling, rendering in computer
>   graphics, or painting shops in car plants.

Alternatively you could read the section on disk scheduling algorithms in any operating systems textbook or look at some algorithms that reduce seek times [here](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~cs561/cs450/disksched/disksched.html), they apply to the line metric space mostly but it should give you a general idea.

Comment: Thank you. I did not expect to get a response to this question almost a year later. Haha. Been a while since I have thought about it. Perusing that paper now.